# Why has my (Dell) monitor suddenly begun changing hues?

Tags: display

My monitor suddenly started changing colors when my pc went into sleep mode. I don't know why and need help to stop it. It's an older Dell monitor and I'm wondering if this is the end of the line for it.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It could be, but I first would start by checking the cables. A loose cable will give the same effect. Try completely unplugging the cable at both ends and inserting them again if the problem persists. If that doesn't solve it, then its likely your monitor is getting near its end of life state.

Comment: Could also be a failing backlight or other circuitry. I had an old LCD that tinted yellow, and would switch back to normal hues when you gave it a bit of a smack.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions:

1. Check to see if the cables are firmly seated on BOTH ends
2. Try replacing the video cable with another known working one.
3. You never say if you have an old CRT or a LED display.  CRT displays age and one of the guns can go out.  Use the existing connections and attach a known working CRT to test this.
4. You can have a problem with the display controller on the pc.  Trying a known monitor may eliminate this.
5. Are all your pc Drivers up-to-date.

These type of diagnostic tests (and some others) will help you isolate the problem and choose the correct path of resolution.

Answer (score 0):

If you're comfortable with the idea of possibly killing it yourself, it could be an internal connection. Consider taking it apart and unplugging and plugging back in (Reseating) all the connectors inside it. like LPChip mentioned about the cables, (correctly) it could be an internal cable.